# Sublime Text 2 keeps asking for permission to save

Tags: macos, authentication, sublimetext2

All of the sudden Sublime Text 2 keeps on asking me if it's okay to save and requiring my mac password.

How can I turn this off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be because you are trying to save your file somewhere other than under your home directory. If you try to save a file somewhere other than your home directory, you will get an authentication request as you normally would not have write permission. Expand the Save dialog box and choose somewhere in your home directory tree and save the file instead.